# Custom design messes upp dialog

Tags: dialog-framework

I have made a custom design on my sharepoint and everything works great. But if i add a new list item or anything that uses the dialog popup. Then it doesnt work.

Its like the dialog window inherits my custom design from the site and i cant see the formular in the dialog. Its like the design pushes away the formular in the dialog so i cant see it. I have added the class="notdlg" to try to hide my custom design in th edialog but that doesnt work either.

Anybody have a clue?

best regards/Stefan

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebug or another element inspector to see which CSS-rules applies to the dialog?

Comment: Did you wrap elements you don't want loading in the dialog by adding the CSS class s4-notdlg to them?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it by using another system masterpage (like v4), the quickest one. But you maybe want your custom masterpage. In that case you can override your css-styles like background for content shown in a modal (popup) dialog. Here is an example:

```
html.ms-dialog body {
    background:#fff;
}
html.ms-dialog ms-bodyareacell, 
html.ms-dialog #ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv, 
html.ms-dialog body #s4-mainarea,
html.ms-dialog .s4-wpTopTable,
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html.ms-dialog body .ms-bodyareacell {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

As you see all these css rules are only for usual elements in a popup dialog.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for your help. But my design from the site are still in the dialogbox... I have now added class="notdlg" on every div but still it shows in my dialogs...

Comment: "s4-notdlg", not just "notdlg". What is shown in your dialogs, which shouldnt be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this class `s4-notdlg` to those elements you don't want shown in the modal dialog, or do as Anatoly Mironov gave you an example on.

Comment: Exactly! But some stuff like body background-image, paddings must be overriden if it doesn't look well in the popup